# Why was my edit flagged as "destructive"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6075577

> Rejected Oct 25 at 2:23: monkeyinsight reviewed this Oct 25 at 2:23:
> Reject This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or
> service, or is deliberately destructive.
>
> andrewsi reviewed this Oct 25
> at 1:58: Reject This edit was intended to address the author of the
> post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a
> comment or an answer.
>
> Pang reviewed this Oct 25 at 1:51: Reject This
> edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense
> as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.
>
> Pokechu22 reviewed this Oct 25 at 1:44: Approve

All I did was edit an older answer with updated information and include information from the external url into the answer itself.

The question was asking if someone should use Typescript or ES6 so I provided an updated blog post to an answer that was referencing and old one.

Edit: Also, is there anything I can do about this or even a way to be notified this happened?

Comment: I'd suspect because the amount of changed text, and stupidity of the actual reviewers, which didn't really see what they're doing. This should be taken into account for a _failed audit_ sample IMHO.

Comment: Destructive? No. Although with the amount of effort put into it; I would have just posted a new answer; especially if you could elaborate more than the verbatim link.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET it wasn't that much effort (link + content from link) and since it was an update to that answers blog post figured it would make more sense there than a separate answer. Thanks for the info though I'll probably just do that next time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reviewers were lazy. Most of them didn't consider your edit to be *destructive* - but they thought it was a reply rather than an addition. That's not your fault; folks just didn't read it carefully.

Something you might want to consider though, which might improve your chances of getting the edit through... This is what you wrote to describe your edit when you submitted it:

> adding updated blog post with info

This is what you write to describe your edit *here*:

> The question was asking if someone should use Typescript or ES6 so I provided an updated blog post to an answer that was referencing and old one.

They convey essentially the same information. But the latter is much more explicit. Particularly considering that reviewers *aren't looking at the question* - they see only the answer you've edited. So if the nature of the question is *at all relevant* to why you're making the change, including the information you did here might make the difference between an edit that is misinterpreted and one that's approved.

Comment: *that reviewers aren't looking at the question - they see only the answer you've edited*. That seems like a huge oversight. How are they supposed to know if the edit is valid or invalid if they can't see what its addressing?

Comment: Whether or not the question matters can depend significantly on what the edit is changing. But I tend to agree - in some other review queues, we do show the question (below the answer when an answer is being reviewed) - that might be a good idea here as well.

Comment: @John They *can* see the question, they just need to go out of their way to go look at it.  The vast majority of edits aren't dependent on the question, even though a rare few are.  The whole idea of the review queue is to put the most important information that is usually relevant in front of the reviewer, and making it *possible* to see everything that they might possibly, but rarely will, need.  When you try to just show *everything* on the review page you make it harder to find the information that's most likely to actually affect the decision.

Comment: @Servy ok well thats better then (I don't have 2k rep to see the edit review queue). Is there anything I can do about a rejected edit since now all my edits have to be queued?

Comment: You could always re-submit the edit with a longer description as I suggested, @John. If it gets rejected again, screw 'em - post your own answer.

Answer (score -10):

Editing others' answers is primarily for correcting minor mistakes (typos, missing words, bad formatting, etc). Adding a relevant quote from an existing link (so as to make an answer no longer link-only) can also be acceptable.

Adding completely new content to someone else's answer is not a proper use of editing. You're putting words in their mouth which, among other things, may cause them to get down-voted. If you want to add completely new content, add your own answer.

Comment: I was adding an updated blog post along with content from that blog post (external url) aka *Adding a relevant quote from an existing link*.

Comment: It looks like you added a *new* link and quoted content from it. That's not the same as bringing in content from a link that the original author put in the answer themselves.

Comment: _"Editing others' answers is primarily for correcting minor mistakes"_ Who was telling you so?!?

Comment: (Suggesting an) edit(ing) (is) exactly *not* for correcting minor issues. Suggested edits must make substantial improvements and correct all major problems.